# getting the click event in a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get the click event for a Kendo Grid so I can bind stuff to shift and ctrl clicking.  I can't use the inherent multiselect Kendo provides because it doesn't support drag and drop.  When I create a function after the dataBound event, my function gets called on clicking, but it's not the typical click event.

```
var onDataBound = function () {
    selectItem.apply(this);
}

grid.dataBound = onDataBound;

var selectItem.apply = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After initializing the `Grid` you should bind a handler to the click event.

Example:

```
$("#grid").on("click", "table", function(e) {
    console.log("clicked", e.ctrlKey, e.altKey, e.shiftKey);
});
```

You can use:

- `e.ctrlKey` for detecting if <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed.
- `e.altKey` for detecting if <kbd>alt</kbd> is pressed.
- `e.shiftKey` for detecting if <kbd>shift</kbd> is pressed.

If you want to detect click only in the body of the table, you can replace `"table"` by `"tbody"` or even `"td"`.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/PgeYC/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `dataBound` event when declaring the grid:

```
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    ,dataBound=onDataBound
});

var onDataBound = function(e)
{
    $("#grid").find("tr").click(selectItem.apply);
};

var selectItem.apply = function (e) {
    var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this);
    if(e.ctrlKey)
       alert('Ctrl + click on ' + dataItem.column1);
}
```

`dataItem` is your bound data item that you can pass around.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It was what I needed for my project, and it is clear and readable for future developers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I believe none of the solutions covered the fact that the event is being applied on the table headers as well. If you have table filters (order by ascending / descending) for example, this might cause problems. The correct way of adding the click event is targetting the table body, as so:

```
$("#grid tbody").find("tr").click(addYourFunctionHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just stop propagation just call **event**.stopPropagation() or **event**.stopImmediatePropagation();

```
function onRowDelete(dataItem) {
           
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    showConfirmation(dataItem);        
}
```