# how to get cell click event in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid, telerik, kendo-grid

My grid is

```
    @(Html.kendo().Grid<StudentViewModel>()
       .Columns( x=>
       {
        x.Bound( y => y.StudentId);
        x.Bound(y => y.SubjectId);
        x.Bound(y => y.Name);
      })
```

here when user clicks on "StudentId" or "SubjectId" cell in those columns want to show a popup, how to get the cell click event and verify that is the right column.
How to get the cell click event ?

Comment: please have a look at this [Link][1]
I hope it helps. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304683/getting-the-click-event-in-a-kendo-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add onto  the previous answers: In your grid, add an event binding

```
@(Html.kendo().Grid<StudentViewModel>()
   .Columns(...)
   .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
  })
```

Then, in your javascript section, add a function like  Arturo suggested:

```
function onChange(arg) {
    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
        return $(item).text();
    });
}
```

This example from Telerik might help: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
 function onChange(arg) {
                var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
                    return $(item).text();
                });
```

And add anything inside you want to be executed.

Comment: I didn't understand, where to subscribe to this Onchange event, can you elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

you can check the event documentation here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/events